# How do I select objects I click on in ArcGIS (.Net)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, c#, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have a `MapView` in my xaml code, which contains several `GraphicsLayer`. The first layer is the actual map, and the second is small `SimpleMarkerSymbol` representing locations.

What do I do to be able to click on them?

I use the trigger `MapViewTapped` which gives me `MapViewInputEventArgs` with coordinates of my click, and I have my `MapView`. According to [the developer guide](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/edit-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_4213B7F672304847B13FD6F9E38622B3), I should be able to do the following:

```
var objectIDs = await lyr.HitTestAsync(MyMapView, myClick.Position);

lyr.SelectGraphics;
```

However, nothing is found. Note: the link uses `FeatureLayer` instead of `GraphicsLayer`.
Unlike `FeatureLayer`, `GraphicsLayer` does not have a setter in its `SelectGraphics` property.

So - how do I click on an marker and have it returned?

Comment: `GraphicsLayer.HitTestAsync` returns `Task<Graphic>`, unlike `FeatureLayer.HitTestAsync` which returns `Task<int64[]>`. Did you try setting `Graphic.IsSelected = true` for your graphics layer?

Comment: This could be useful, @KirkKuykendall. I set the ``Graphic.IsSelected = true``, and noted something is located. It sees the actual dot, but I can't get any info on what it is. It sees my dot i blue, and 8 pixels wide, but nothing to really identify it. I will update when I get more solid data on this. If you have further suggestions, feel free to share them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, which works for me:

```
var layer = Map.Layers[MyLayer] as GraphicsLayer;
var selectedId = await layer.HitTestAsync(mapView, eventargs.Position);
selectedId.IsSelected = true; //Nothing found sets selectedId = null
var unitsFound = layer.SelectedGraphics.ToList();
```

This gives a list of all units found at the point you clicked. But it only gives you the coordinates.
But match this with the list of units added to your map, and you can find potential units you clicked:

```
var foundUnits = new List<MyUnitClass>();

foreach (var unit in unitsFound)
{
    var unitCoord = (MapPoint) unit.Geometry;
    foundUnits.Add(layer.MyAddedUnits.FirstOrDefault(
        x => x.Information.Coordinate.Latitude == unitCoord.Y &&
             x.Information.Coordinate.Longitude == unitCoord.X));
}

return foundUnits;
```

It is also [explained on their website](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/use-the-mvvm-design-pattern.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6BD3A54742C645119AA7A5FA05C3EA62) to some extent.